# FieldRenderProps with React Native TextInput

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-final-form

I created custom TextInput for final-form in React-Native. And I need to specify type for FieldRenderProps. And I have an error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: TextInputProps | Readonly<TextInputProps>): TextInput',
 gave the following error.     
Type '{ name: string; onBlur: 
(event?: FocusEvent<HTMLElement, Element> | undefined) => void; 
onChange: (event: any) => void; onFocus: (event?: FocusEvent<HTMLElement, Element> | undefined) => void; type?: string | undefined; value: TextInputProps; 
checked?: boolean | undefined; multiple?: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<TextInputProps>'.
```

So my CustomInput code:

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import {FieldRenderProps} from 'react-final-form';
import {TextInput, TextInputProps} from 'react-native';

const AuthInput: FC<FieldRenderProps<TextInputProps>> = ({input}) => {
  return <TextInput {...input} />;
};

export default AuthInput;
```

Can you help, what type I need in FieldRenderProps?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of generic `FieldRenderProps` is `FieldValue`. When `FieldRenderProps` is used with one or two parameters, `InputValue` is defaulted to `FieldValue`. Afaik, `InputValue` for `TextInput` should be string. So the type definition for AuthInput can be `FC<FieldRenderProps<string>>`